# How can I put text , image and symbols together through one field

Tags: asp.net, html

I am creating a website for creating test papers for maths , physics etc, as it is not accepting special symbols.

(1.)    If sin(symbol theta) then the general value of  is

(a) 2n(pie symbol)
(b)  4(pie symbol)
(c)
(d) None of these

I have done rest all but it is taking only simple text questions , not symbols.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on Google lead me here: http://barzilai.org/math_sym.htm.

So, instead of typing the word, or trying to copy in the symbol from whatever text editor you are using, simply copy in the little set of characters from this website, and it should show the character in the website.

Comment: My users will type in Word and copy paste from their or upload word or excel file.

Comment: @User995426 In that case, you'd have to implement a system where either they have access to those conversions, or the input area does something automatically when a specific word is typed in: if they type theta, the text box recognises this and swaps that word for the escaped characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here you see a conversion table http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html

**Usage**

You can just use it in your HTML, for instance

```
<div>This is the capital letter phi: &#934;</div>
```